# How to find similar transactions in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana

I have question here, how can find similar functions in elastic search ? Example - I have application and it have different process
Get ChipController/processpackage

Get ChipController/processfollowup
Get ChipController/processincoming

I would like to find all these process with one expression.
How that is possible in elastic search ?

Tried with dissect but not went well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here the two transactions which are processfollowup and processincomplete. If I want group all transactions/process which has same name but different suffix at the end of transactions name.